# Rails: How to change this link into a button?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Right now I can call a method using ajax (:remote=> 'true') at `awisprotect_path` by simply clicking on the "x" in this link

```
<%= link_to "x", 
    awisprotect_path,
  :remote => true,
  :method => :post,
  %>
```

The controller action  renders jquery so the response is included into the html in the view

```
<div class="awishanswer">

</div>
```

That's all working fine. However, instead of having an "x" to click, I wanted the user to click a button and get the same result.   So I essentially just wanted to put the link info

```
<%= link_to "x", 
    awisprotect_path,
  :remote => true,
  :method => :post,
  %>
```

into this button

```
 <button class="btn small primary" >
                    check
</button>
```

So I created this form and put it in a partial

```
<%= form_tag(:controller => "sessions", :action => "awisprotect", :remote => true, :method => "post") do %>


 <button type="submit" class="btn small secondary">check awis</button>

 <% end %>
```

but the problem is that the controller action that renders js is not putting the result of the action into the html div. Instead, it's redirecting to a blank page and then printing the jquery method with the result that I was checking for with the controller action. the blank page just shows this...

```
$('div.awishanswer').html(' html to be inserted in div');
```

Can anyone explain?

In the url it says

```
http://localhost:3000/awisprotect?method=post&remote=true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**in the view file**

```
<div class="awishanswer" id="awishanswer">
    <% form_remote_tag :url => {:controller => "sessions", :action => "awisprotect"}, 
                    :html => {:method => "post"}, :update => "awishanswer" do %>
        <input type="submit" class="btn small primary" value="check" />
    <% end %>
</div>
```

**in the action**

```
def awisprotect
    @flag = params[:flag] // suppose sending parameter flag from form
   // do something
   render :partial => 'partial file containing html to send to view'
end
```

1. The `form` will be `submitted` when the `submit` `button` is `clicked`.
2. the action will send the html contained in partial file.
3. the `form` will `update` the div with id provided in form with the html code send back from action.

**EDIT:partial file**

```
<%if @flag%>
// include some html
<%else%>
// include some other html
<%end%>
```

Comment: you say the action will send the html contained in the partial file, but can this partial file's html be generated dynamically? For example, my action determines whether a value submitted from the form is true or false, and the partial will need to reflect the result of the controller action.  Is it possible to update this partial depending on the results of the action?

Comment: yeah of course.. you pass the parameter from the form to action and check the value in action and the use rails scriplet in the partial file. i am including an example in answer. pls check it

Comment: o.k, thanks a lot, but this is sort of violating MVC, isn't it? putting controller logic in a view?  does it matter?

Comment: i have added a variable "@flag" in action retrieving using params and using it in partial view considering "flag" is sent from form.

Comment: o.k, thanks, so in the view, @flag would come from the "name" of the form input, like this? <select name="flag"  class="blah">  is that right?

Comment: nope it doesn't matter.. Its not controller logic, we are not implementing any business logic or anything, we are just using a variables in view..thats completely fair, it wont violate the MVC.. i have been using a lot of place in my application.

Comment: yeah it can come.. you will have to compare according to data type thats all. i mean something like flag =="abc" because from <input> it will always be string right.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your getting a problem is probably because of your usage of the `form_tag` helper uses the :remote and :method values inside the url generation instead of being handled be the form. The correct usage would probably be like this:

```
<%= form_tag({:controller => "sessions", :action => "awisprotect"}, 
              :remote => true, 
              :method => "post")
```

However, Rails already has a helper method to create a button to submit data called `button_to`. It basically takes the exact same arguments as the `link_to` helper so I would probably use it like this in your case:

```
<%= button_to "x", awisprotect_path, :remote => true, :method => :post %>
```

The :method argument could possibly even be left out because I think the button_to helper defaults to the POST protocol.

Answer (score 1):

You can disguise a link as a button, using some CSS. Here's a [nice article](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/11/18/designing-css-buttons-techniques-and-resources/).

This might be better than all these experiments with partials and forms. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking you didn't wrap the options for form_tag properly.  Try something like this:

```
form_tag( { :controller => :sessions, :action => :awisprotect, :method => post }, { :remote => true } ) do ....
```

It may or may not also help to use `button_tag`.

Comment: horizontal scrolling is evil :-)

Comment: Hah yep just realized that ;p